# How to do math on pgfkeys arguments and asign them to other keys

Tags: calculations, pgfkeys

I'm trying to reduce the work load of applying some overlays over and over with different numbers. However, I need to compute for a given frame the next or previous one, thus needing to do simple arithmetic on the given value.

This task, however, turned out to be quite difficult with the little knowledge of pgfkeys I have.

The code below shows what I'm trying to do

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  onslide/.code args={<#1>#2}{%
    \only<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}} 
  },
  mycolor/.style={text=red},
  opaque/.style={opacity=0.5, text opacity=0.5},
  animate/.style={onslide=<#1>{mycolor}, onslide=<#1+1>{opaque}},
}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]{Same with forest}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% I want something like this
\node[rectangle, animate=1] at (0,1) {On slide 1};
\node[rectangle, animate=2] at (0,2) {On slide 2};
\node[rectangle, animate=3] at (0,3) {On slide 3};

% Instead of something like this
%\node[rectangle, onslide=<1>{mycolor}, onslide=<2>{opaque}] at (0,1) {On slide 1};
%\node[rectangle, onslide=<2>{mycolor}, onslide=<3>{opaque}] at (0,2) {On slide 2};
%\node[rectangle, onslide=<3>{mycolor}, onslide=<4>{opaque}] at (0,3) {On slide 3};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the `#1+1` does not work out of the box in the key.

```
  animate/.style={onslide=<#1>{mycolor}, onslide=<#1+1>{opaque}}
```

I also try with a `\pgfmathparse` and a `\pgfmathsetmacro` but that didn't work either. I think it has to do with the expansion of the keys or the scope of the macros.

So, how can I make that type of thing to work automatically. Also, bonus points if you can give a general case in which I can handle `+-` ranges too. But that is not necessary right now.

Comment: You have to call `\animate=1`, not `animate=<1>`. However, if I try to pass `#1+1` with `\expandafter\only\expandafter<\the\numexpr#1>`, `beamer` doesn't stop.

Comment: Yea my bad, the `animate=<1>` is an error when putting it here. But the idea is the same. And the `#1+1` is the problem I'm trying to tackle. I think I am not allowed to do that sum straightforward.

Comment: No, of course `\only<1+1>` cannot be interpreted correctly by `beamer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For obvious reasons this produces four overlays, but the idea should be clear: you have to pass the explicit number to `\only`, which can be done with `\numexpr`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  onslide/.code args={<#1>#2}{%
    \expandafter\only\expandafter<\the\numexpr#1\relax>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}%
  },
  mycolor/.style={text=red},
  opaque/.style={opacity=0.5, text opacity=0.5},
  animate/.style={onslide=<#1>{mycolor}, onslide=<#1+1>{opaque}},
}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]{Same with forest}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% I want something like this
\node[rectangle, animate={1}] at (0,1) {On slide 1};
\node[rectangle, animate={2}] at (0,2) {On slide 2};
\node[rectangle, animate={3}] at (0,3) {On slide 3};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Cool, that solves the issue with the numbers, but is not compatible with `+-` expressions on the overlays. Is there a way to use the `\numexpr` with that? How does beamer handle such things?

Comment: @adn Much more work is needed, for that. But that was not in your question. You should add *all* the specifications needed: do you just need `+-` or some other constructions? In another question, please.