# How to do math on overlay arguments using pgfkeys (handle numbers and ranges)

Tags: calculations, pgfkeys

### Context

I'm [trying to do some basic operations on arguments on `pgfkeys`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275474/how-to-do-math-on-pgfkeys-arguments-and-asign-them-to-other-keys), and got stuck while trying to do simple arithmetic on them. Thankfully, [`egreg` gave a nice solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275482/7561) for handling the arithmetic of the overlays.

### Problem

So, the problem at hand. I want a robust way of handling the arguments of overlays to be used in `pgfkeys` to be able to do arithmetic with them (for example `<#1+2>` or `<2*#1-1>`), but also to be able to handle the ranges on them nicely (for example `<2->` or `<+->`). On the ranges, I'm not sure if adding to the start or end of the range is possible but that will be handy too (for example, given as input `<2->` and an argument that looks like `<#1+1>` we should obtain `<3->` as range when computed).

`egreg`'s solution is quite nice, as it uses `\numexpr` to expand the arithmetic on the `onslide` key. However, how this solution can be expanded to accommodate such intricate cases?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  onslide/.code args={<#1>#2}{%
    \expandafter\only\expandafter<\the\numexpr#1\relax>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}%
  },
  mycolor/.style={text=red},
  opaque/.style={opacity=0.5, text opacity=0.5},
  animate/.style={onslide=<#1>{mycolor}, onslide=<#1+1>{opaque}},
}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]{Same with forest}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% This works
\node[rectangle, animate={1}] at (0,1) {On slide 1};
\node[rectangle, animate={2}] at (0,2) {On slide 2};
\node[rectangle, animate={3}] at (0,3) {On slide 3};
% But this doesn't
\node[rectangle, animate={4-}] at (0,3) {On slide 4};
\node[rectangle, animate={+-}] at (0,3) {On slide 5};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

So, the expansions should look like this:

- Input `#1 := 1`, then `<#1>` and `<#1+1>` should become `<1>` and `<2>`
- Input `#1 := 2-`, then `<#1>` and `<#1+1>` should become `<2->` and `<3->`
- Input `#1 := +-`, then `<#1>` and `<#1+1>` should become `<+->` and `<+(1)->`

That is, basically, performing the operation on the range given. Probably for complex ranges it will be more difficult.

### Summary

So, in summary, I'm just trying to do math on the argument to be able to change the ranges at will inside a `pgfkey`. However, as the arguments are not parsed as numbers it turned to be more difficult. Thus, a simple work around to operate on the inputs and the ranges will be fine too.

Comment: If you use `animate={+-}` you are specifying `onslide=<+-+1>`, which I can't assign a sensible meaning to. What should be done when you say `animate={+-}`? As it stands the question cannot be answered.

Comment: I was expecting something when I input `+-` to do the plus one operation into that range, so it should be something like `+(1)-`. And the problem is what you say, you can't just add one to the range, so somehow the range should be decomposed, and then perform the operation to it, and reconstruct the range to pass it to the argument. I saw that beamer supports some offsets, but couldn't make them work either. But making it work with offsets is a different story.

Comment: One should essentially rewrite the parser. Are these the only possible cases? (1) `<number>` (2) `<number>-<number>` (3) `<number>-` (4) `+-`? What should be done in each case?

Comment: Well, if you are trying to go for the parser I will suggest a general case. Something like `<exp>-<exp>` where `<exp>` can either be a `<number>`, `+` (auto increment), `<exp> <op> <exp>` (where `<op>` can be any arithmetic operator), and ` ` (empty).

Comment: I'm not sure about `<op>` to be *any* operator; in any case, the specification which is still missing is what to do in the second `onslide`.

Comment: I'm expecting to see the operation on the range. For example, if you have `#1+1-`, and if `#1` is a number just do the math, if it is a `+` or `.` do an offset.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand. *What should a specification become in the second `onslide`?* It shouldn't be so difficult to give, *in the question*, a ***complete*** specification. Guessing is not my preferred activity. Bye.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making `<1,3-4,+->` into `<2,4-5,+(1)->` you can modify `\beamer@slideinframe`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    onslide'/.code args={<#1>[#2]#3}{%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\beamer@slideinframe{\beamer@slideinframe-#2}%
        \expandafter\only\expandafter<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}%
    },
    onslide/.code args={<#1>#2}{%
        \expandafter\only\expandafter<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}%
    },
    mycolor/.style={text=red},
    opaque/.style={opacity=0.5, text opacity=0.5},
    animate/.style={onslide={<#1>{mycolor}}, onslide'={<#1>[+1]{opaque}}},
}
    \begin{frame}[plain]{Same with forest}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[rectangle, animate={1}] at (0,1) {On slide 1};
            \node[rectangle, animate={2}] at (0,2) {On slide 2};
            \node[rectangle, animate={3}] at (0,3) {On slide 3};
            \node[rectangle, animate={4-}] at (0,4) {On slide 4};
            \node[rectangle, animate={+-}] at (0,5) {On slide 5};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \vfill\hfill
        ((this is slide \the\beamer@slideinframe))
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]